# Navigating trough objects of a web page, using an embedded web browser

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a Windows Forms application that uses a `WebBrowser` control to display an embedded web page. The file is (successfully) loaded using:

```
webHelp.DocumentStream=
          Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
          .GetManifestResourceStream("MyAssembly.help.html");
```

In order for this to work (i.e. the file to be loaded/displayed) I set the `webHelp.AllowNavigation = false;`. I don't fully understand why, but if it's set to true, the page is not displayed.

In my HTML document (see bellow) I want to be able to navigate trough different sections. But when I click on a link, the browser control does not go to the targeted element. The web page works fine in the stand-alone Internet Explorer 10, so it must have something to do with the control, more specifically the `AllowNavigation` property. MSDN didn't help much.

How can I achieve this navigation behavior? Is there another way of loading the HTML file without setting the `AllowNavigation` property to false?

This is my simple HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Using this tool</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Description</h3>
    <div><p id="contents">Contents</p></div>
    <div>
        <p id="general">Using the file converter</p>
        <p>*converter description*</p>
        <a href="#contents" class="goToTop">Go To Top!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="divBlock" >
        <p id="selectOption">Selecting a conversion action</p>
        <p>*action selection*</p>
        <a href="#contents" class="goToTop">Go To Top!</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** After additional tests I found the root of the problem. The problem appeared after setting a value for the `URL` property, running the application and afterwards clearing this value. The embedded page is not loaded any more, unless the `AllowNavigation` property is set to `false`. There are two solutions, described in my answer bellow.

Comment: I guess we missed the trees for the forest here :) Why do you set `WebBrowser.AllowNavigation` to `false`, in the first place? It's `true` by default, and `WebBrowser.DocumentStream` works just fine when it's `true`.

Comment: @Noseratio, I can't figure out why, but my embedded web page does not get loaded if `AllowNavigation` is `true`... It's the same with `DocumentText` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** After finding the cause of the problem (see the edit to the question) I can now propose three solutions:

**1. `WebBrowser` control replacement:**
Simply delete the existing `WebBrowser` control and add a new one. This solution does not require any modification of the `AllowNavigation` property. DO NOT modify the `URL` property.

**2. When deleting and adding a new `WebBrowser` control is not an option:**
Since the `AllowNavigation` property was influencing the loading and displaying of the web page, there was no reason for it to be left to `false` afterwards. Setting back the property in the `Shown` event solved the navigation problem, without requiring other alterations (e.g. in the HTML file or the Registry):

```
private void helpForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webHelp.AllowNavigation = true;
}
```

**3. Reseting the `Document`**
It seams that the `Document` property gets (automatically) initialized if `URL` property is at one time set and reset. Adding `webHelp.Document.OpenNew(true);` before loading the resource stream solves the problem without the need for re-adding the `WebBrowser` and without modifying the `AllowNavigation` property.

Comment: This is a bit odd, because `WebBrowser.AllowNavigation` is `true` by default. Do you set it to `false` somewhere else?

Comment: @Noseratio, for some reason, the page doesn't get loaded if it's embedded, unless I set `AllowNavigation` to `false` before the loading. I set it to `false` in the properties window, so it starts that way. My solution does not work if I set it to `true` right after I load the page. It must be set after the window gets `Shown`.

Comment: Your code works for me unmodified inside `Form.Load` event on a simple form which has just a `WebBrowser` control with all default settings. Check the properties of your `WebBrowser` in the Designer, you probably have something wrong in there.

Comment: @Noseratio, that's really strange. I have only modified the `AllowNavigation` property in the Designer (and of course the size and position).

Comment: It is indeed strange, I'd be concerned. Try to find the problem by removing your code piece by piece, until you have a stripped-down app that works, like the wizard-generated app I just described above. Or do the other way round, by adding pieces to the barebone app.

Answer (score 0):

I also have my own WebBrowser.  I've tested it and it loads your HTML file perfectly. 
I simply used:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("C:\\myPath\\SofNavigate.html");
```

When I click on links it goes to "#contents" without problems. 
I am not sure why you need to use webHelp.Docstream instead of simple Navigate. 
By the way, when I turn off navivation, then I am not able to go anywhere from the page that I started on. So Navigation **must** be on in order to go anywhere from the "home page".

Try to debug that part, as it appears to be the bigger problem that you have.
Here is a good [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8ys666.aspx) on how to set up simple webBrowser.  Try to use it as a base and see what you do differently that messes up your navigation.

Comment: Exactly what I suspected. However, I'm trying to keep my HTML file embedded, so loading it from disk is kind of a last resort.

Comment: @AndreiV it doesn't have to be loaded from the disk. webBrowser.Navigate("http://yourpage.com")

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have looked at the `Navigate` method but couldn't generate a URL from the embedded resource. As I previously said, loading from an embedded resource is an important request for my application.

Comment: @AndreiV then I am out of ideas. :( 
Hope that someone else will help you out. If I get some new ideas, I will come back to this post.

Comment: Cant you just set browser.DocumentText to whatever html string you want? That usually works for me...

Comment: @MattiasÅslund I tried that too. That didn't work when `AllowNavigation = false;`.

Comment: @Andrei; My suggestion was of course in combination with leaving `AllowNavigation=true`, but I suspect from your answer that that didn't work for you?

Comment: @MattiasÅslund, thank you. I expected it to work. Unfortunately that was influenced by some weird bug (described above in my question and answer).

Answer (score 0):

**[EDITED]** Win8/IE10, your code works for me unmodified inside `Form.Load` event on a simple form which has just a single `WebBrowser` control with all default settings (and `WebBrowser.AllowNavigation` is `true` by default). Check the properties of your `WebBrowser` control in the Designer, you may have something wrong in there.
**[/EDITED]**

You're using HTML5, which handles anchor links via `id` attribute (i.e. `<p id="contents"> ... <a href="#contents">`. By default, `WebBrowser` control works in legacy IE7 mode with HTML5 disabled. You need to turn it on with [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) feature control, before `WebBrowser` object gets created. The best place to do this is a `static` constructor of your form:

```
static MainForm()
{
    SetBrowserFeatureControl();
}

private static void SetBrowserFeatureControl()
{
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation

    // FeatureControl settings are per-process
    var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

    // make sure the control is not running inside Visual Studio Designer
    if (String.Compare(fileName, "devenv.exe", true) == 0 || String.Compare(fileName, "XDesProc.exe", true) == 0)
        return;

    // web pages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in Standards mode
    using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
        @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
        RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
    {
        key.SetValue(fileName, (UInt32)9000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
}
```

Try it and your links should work as expected. This solution **does NOT require admin rights**, the affected key is under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

**[UPDATE]** There may be a better solution, it works at least for IE10 here on my side. Add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` as below and leave the registry intact. If you see `document.compatMode: CSS1Compat, document.documentMode: 10`, you should be good to go, but test with older IE versions too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            info.firstChild.data = 
                "document.compatMode: " + document.compatMode +
                ", document.documentMode: " + document.documentMode;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <pre id="info">&nbsp;</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Noseration Thanks for your answer. My application needs to be self contained (ergo my embedded resource problem) and not depend on environment settings (other than SO, .Net and such). The need for adding/changing registry keys is not valid as I don't really know the credential policy of any of the clients.

Comment: I've just seen your edit. I've found a solution which, in my opinion, is simpler (see my answer). I will, however, test yours and check back.

Comment: I tried your solution and unfortunately it didn't work. The registry key gets added but the behavior does not change. My solution worked without this key set, so I believe that in this case, it doesn't make any difference whether or not it is present.

Comment: @AndreiV, interesting. If your solution works for you, then the problem is solved. You still may want to check my latest update, to make sure your page does run in the standard mode.

Comment: @Noseratio_ tried it and got `document.compatMode: CSS1Compat, document.documentMode: 10`, but it didn't work. (Off topic: any reason for the "@" reference not to work?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40552/discussion-between-andrei-v-and-noseratio)